# Is there a way to exclude certain files to be type-checked by webpack's dev server using Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So I have a project in Vue 2 developed on TypeScript. I noticed every time there's a change, and Webpack's dev server recompiles, a type check is run on the whole project.

In order to avoid in order to save some computation time, and to clean up a bit the console from non-relevant error messages, is to exclude my test files `*.spec.ts` from this type check.

[image]

I've tried several things, including this vue-cli [plugin](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html#configuration), and with this webpack [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to have the desired behavior.

I also tried to add this to `tsconfig.json`, but it doesn't work.

```
"exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules"]
```

Comment: "I also tried to add this to tsconfig.json" - this is what needs to be done. The obvious reason for it to not work is that tsconfig isn't used for some reason. Try to make syntax mistake there and see what happens

Comment: @EstusFlask somehow when I modify `tsconfig.json` file the type checking stops, but modules are not resolved anymore. Specifically, those resolves using webpack (relative paths, e.g. `import something from '@/utils/something';`) and Vue single-file-components e.g. `import Component from '@/components/Component`. I already have Shims for `.vue` imports, I'm not sure what's wrong with Webpack. To be honest I'm rather noob with it (I avoid touching it :()